How to fix below error according to flutter and firebase?
How to fix that Error
"while trying to load an asset: Flutter Web engine failed to fetch "assets/". HTTP request succeeded, but the server responded with HTTP status 404.
Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: "".  "
I am going to connect flutter codes with firebase

I linked a question about the same error message that has some highly voted answers. If your problem is not addressed there, edit your question (there's a link right under it for this purpose) to clarify how it's different from the link.
